# jQuery - parseInt() always returns NaN

Tags: jquery, nan, parseint

I created a little function which adds a row in a table. This works fine. But now I have a problem with the `parseInt()` part.

The first row of the table contains an `ID`, which brings me to the if-clause. So good, so fine.
But in the second run it alerts the `1` but uses this as a string and response with `NaN`.

So, where is my problem?

```
function AddFlas(){
    if($(".Flasvalues").is(":hidden")){
        $(".Flasvalues").slideToggle(300);
    }

    var par = $("#Flastable tr:last");
    var tdt = par.children("td:nth-child(1)").text(); 
    tdt = parseInt(tdt,10);
    alert(tdt); // First run: ID, Second: 1, Third: 1
    if (tdt != "NaN"){
        alert("is NaN");
        tdt = 0;
    }
    tdt++;
    alert(tdt);
    $("#Flastable tbody").append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td>"+tdt+"</td>"+
        "<td><input name='Flas' type='text'></td>"+
        "<td><input name='Flaskgm' type='number' min='0' step='any'></td>"+
        "<td align='center'><img src='styles/save.png' class='btnSaveFlas'><img src='styles/trash.png' class='btnDeleteFlas'></td>"+
        "</tr>");

    addPointer();
    $(".btnSaveFlas").bind("click", SaveFlas);      
    $(".btnDeleteFlas").bind("click", DeleteFlas);              
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `isNaN()` as shown below :

Instead of

```
if (tdt != "NaN"){
```

Try

```
if (isNaN(tdt)){
```

OR Try

```
tdt = parseInt(tdt,10) || 0;  //if 'paresInt()' fails to parse value in int it will return 0
```

if you use second answer then there will be no need of

```
if (tdt != "NaN"){
    alert("is NaN");
    tdt = 0;
}
```

code block(which is wrong although) in your code.

Comment: Now, I feel me a little bit stupid. Both works fine. Thank you. =D

Comment: @MarcoWinkler...haha..your welcome..everyday we learn something new so plz don't feel stupid it was a good question...thanks..

Answer (score 1):

you can youse following syntax to get it .. it work always with undefined and Nan but will fails when float.

```
+ tdt || 0
```